# Is it possible in git to show differences from multiple not necessarily successive commits? (git diff A..B but with some commits in between omitted)

Tags: git, version-control, diff

In my team we're experimenting with this concept of "feature branches". It has to do with subfeatures in that some features can be further split into subtasks, that are dependent on one another.

What I want is to see the compressed diffs from multiple commits on a branch.

Example of some kind of git log output:

Commit hash, author, comment

```
1234, John, TASK-123 made the button red
4121, Susan, TASK-321 made the bar green
3322, John, TASK-123 made the button work
4412, Susan, TASK-321 made the bar work
```

I'd want to see the diffs only for those commits whose comment contains "TASK-123", so that I can see exactly the changes that were made regarding that one task. (Of course, the commits for that task coincide with the commits made by the author John). So The exact way the filtering works is a little irrelevant, I just want to see the changes in those commits - assuming they did NOT change the same lines.

Is this possible somehow? I know I can view diffs for successive commits `git diff commit1..commit2`.... but what I want is to filter out some commit ranges basically.

Disclaimer: We might be doing this whole thing wrong and there might be a better way of doing this - if there is and you can explain/provide documentation, please do. The reason why we are doing this is so that we can release easier on our testing environments - again, if you have better ideas on how we can do this, I'm completely open.

Comment: `git show <commit>`?

Comment: @ElpieKay I need to see a diff from multiple commits combined. What you wrote only shows the diffs from 1 commit. If I write `git show commit1 commit2 commit3` then i see the concatenated output the 3 `git show` commands. Not what I want - I want 3 different diffs in 1 file, not 1 different diff in 3 files (assuming i had made 3 changes in the same file)

Comment: Why don't you have a feature branch per task instead? In your example I see no reason why commits from different tasks would be pushed in between on another. If I am working on TASK-123, I should not push my commits before I have completed the task, same for the developer working on TASK-321. In addition to this I would suggest not pushing multiple commits on one task, but using local feature branches, and squashing the commits before pushing.

Comment: @sp1nakr collaborating on code would work well when each of the developers worked on their respective tasks on their own branches. However, when deploying on an environment where we need to test the application, AND there are dependencies between tasks, things get tougher. I didn't find an easy way to do things differently.... only other way would be to merge branches into a "deployment" branch and deploy that, then re-merge and re-deploy when changes appear.... that could work too I guess, we need to explore that option too

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but in general I would advice against "inventing" new branching strategies etc. See https://kofoedanders.com/git-cooperation-simplified , for more details and references.

Comment: In the specific case you are describing I still don't see how you would end up with TASK-123, TASK-321, TASK-123, TASK-321, in that order, even if working on the same branch. John shouldn't push his commits before finishing his task, same for Susan

Comment: @vlad-ardelean have you solved the problem yet? If there has the answer help you solve the problem, you can mark it as answer. And it will benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 3):

Without addressing any of the work-flow issues, i.e., looking only at the question:

> I know I can view diffs for successive commits `git diff commit1..commit2` ... but what I want is to filter out some commit ranges [and get the effect of: what happens if I make a new branch, cherry-pick some set of commits into that branch, and then compare the tip of that branch with the base of that branch]?

The answer is that you cannot get this from `git diff`.  The syntax:

```
git diff c1..c2
```

literally means *exactly the same thing as*:

```
git diff c1 c2
```

The `..` notation here is essentially thrown away entirely.  (The *way* `git diff` does this is a bit cheesy and hacky.  If you feed the `c1..c2` notation to `git rev-parse` you will see that it converts to `c2 ^c1`.  Internally, `git diff` invokes the same code that `git rev-parse` uses, then it examines the result: if there's one negated commit `^<hash>` and one positive commit `<hash>`, it extracts the content of the negated commit, extracts the comment of the positive commit, and diffs those two contents.)

The bracketed text I added suggests a way you can produce what you intended: instead of trying to diff commit `c1` vs commit `c2` "as if" some in-between commits had been removed, you can:

```
$ git checkout -b tempbranch c1
$ git cherry-pick <insert list of commits in the c1..c2 range you want>
... resolve any conflicts here if necessary ...
$ git diff c1 HEAD
```

In other words, to find out what would happen if you cherry picked some list of commits, you must cherry-pick that list of commits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought that my fallback plan would be to cherry pick all commits I cared about on their own branch (while hoping there are no conflicts) and look at the diff that way.

Comment: If there only is a few commits you want to skip, it might be less hassle to do an interactive rebase and remove the unwanted commits instead of cherry-picking.

Comment: @hlovdal good point - check out a duplicate branch and then rebase that, dropping the commits I don't want. I think that is the closest thing to what I want, will experiment with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about features branches as in GitHubFlow, I don't see how you end up with the commit order you show, since John should not push his commit before finishing his task, same for Susan, thus you would get the following order:

1234, John, TASK-123 made the button red

3322, John, TASK-123 made the button work

4121, Susan, TASK-321 made the bar green

4412, Susan, TASK-321 made the bar work

Then you can deploy, and test the feature branch whenever you want, since the remote branch will only contain finished work.

For more info on branching strategies see:

- [Git Cooperation - From fancy to Functioning](https://kofoedanders.com/git-cooperation-simplified/)
- [Github Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/)
- [Enabling Trunk Based Development with Deployment Pipelines](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/enabling-trunk-based-development-deployment-pipelines)

Comment: So that's the thing, our flow is different than the gitflow. The gitflow doesn't really help with deployments out of the box, we're spending too much time merging and re-merging branches before deployments... That's why we decided to just work on the same branch... Thx for the answer though :)